# updated code for space below listview

Tags: android

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/_tv_title_labels"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Profile Labels :"
        android:textColor="@drawable/black"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />                 

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/_tv_title_labels">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/asda"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/TableLayout01"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/_lv_labels"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="380dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" >
            </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/asda"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="bottom">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
                android:gravity="bottom" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/_btn_scannewitem"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:text="Scan New Item" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/_btn_saveNewItem"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:text="Save Your Item"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/_btn_changeprofile"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:text="Change Profile" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

But this free space is found above the button when the free space is removed below text. my page should not contain free space.
i have updated the code as you have suggested but dint find any change in my design.
Still have the space issue.
[image: here the space is found below "Profile labels"]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'you have told'. U cant chat using questions and answers. And when u get an answer that u want accept it else nobody going to help.

Comment: I'd not understood the question completely, you'd better provide more detailed description, possibly with screenshot. However, I see that ' android:paddingTop="20dp"' will add a space above button. Is that the problem you want to eliminate?